# Text on latheGeometry

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, three.js

Here is a little example of what i'm trying to achieve:

http://www.artlineatvb.it/test_3d/test_10

Now i don't know how to position the text correctly on the external surface, how to fill exactly the entire ring without stretching the text and some other things!
I need help, if there is someone interested in this work, we can pay for it!
Thank you!

Comment: definitely @mrdoob will answer the question :)

Comment: Hmm, do you mind quickly sketching up how it should look like?

Comment: Should be something like this http://www.artlineatvb.it/images/anello_04.png